# How do I automate pressing the F5 key using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

This should be very simple, but I can't get it to work

```
do
wscript.sleep 3000
shellobj.sendkeys "{F5}"
loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this way :

```
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
do
    wscript.sleep 3000
    ws.sendkeys "{F5}"
loop
```